# Force node.js to use bin/bash instead of sh

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, sh

I'm trying to execute a basic bash script from node using the `exec()` function.  The bash script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in $1/*.mov ; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -c copy $1/output.mov
```

The script works fine running it from the command line but when running from within node I get a syntax error:  `line 2: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

It appears when running this command node it attempting to use `sh` instead of `bash`.  Can anyone verify this is true and give a possible workaround or solution? Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Interesting.  Is bash actually at /bin/bash?  If you use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` does it work without explicitly calling bash from node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [child_process.execFile](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) or just explicitly run `['/bin/bash', '/path/to/your/script.sh', arg1, arg2...]`.

Comment: This gave me `broken pipe` error messages (note quite sure why), but the concept helped.  I switched from `execFile` to `child_process.spawn('bash',[script])` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Provided you're on a recent version of Node, you can add the following as option for exec:

```
{shell: "/bin/bash"}
```

See: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: What's up dude!
Your tip was useful for me. 
Here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657542/how-to-use-tee-command-inside-child-process-exec 
Setting {shell: "/ bin / bash"} inside of exec, I was able to solve my problem.
Thanks.