# How to use tee command inside child process (exec)?

Tags: node.js, openssl, child-process, pem, pfx

I'm trying to use the tee command inside the exec, but I can't get any progress. 
My command converts a PFX to a PEM certificate using openssl like that:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in MYCERT.pfx -nodes -passin pass:123456 | tee >(openssl pkey -outform PEM) >(openssl x509 -outform PEM)
```

Terminal output:

```
# first command output (PFX to PEM)
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 1A 0F 62 99 24 06 E7 AE D7 0F 11...

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIH+zCCBeOgAwIBAgIQXSw4HKLTQrztT3ENqlcWfjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB4
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJCUjETMB ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

# second command output (public key)
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIH+zCCBeOgAwIBAgIQXSw4HKLTQrztT3ENqlcWfjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB4
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJCUjETMBEGA1UEChMKSUNQLUJyYXN...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

# third command output (private key)
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDES17GiaEXojOa
EoK5cf5mJp+saKXst3uqbznnf...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The first part of the command above converts my PFX file to a PEM file (`openssl pkcs12 -in MYCERT.pfx -nodes -passin pass:123456`).

Soon after, the content from first is sent to the second command (`openssl pkey -outform PEM`) where I extract my private key and to the third command(`openssl x509 -outform PEM`) where I extract my public key.

It works perfectly at the Linux terminal, but fails when used by exec.

My Node code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exports.readPkcs12 = (pfx, password, callback) => {
  const fileName = path.join('/', 'tmp', `${uuid()}.pfx`);
  fs.writeFileSync(fileName, pfx);

  exec(
    `openssl pkcs12 -in ${fileName} -nodes -passin pass:${password} | tee >(openssl x509 -outform PEM) >(openssl pkey -outform PEM)`,
    (error, stdout, _stderr) => {
      console.log(stdout, error);
      if (error) return callback(error);
      callback(null, stdout);
    }
  );
};
```

Error output:

```
 { Error: Command failed: openssl pkcs12 -in /tmp/5dcee6b8-6b25-4765-bd17-c0a84d2bcbb5.pfx -nodes -passin pass:brlog18 | tee >(openssl x509 -outform PEM) >(openssl pkey -outform PEM)
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:299:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:481:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:481:20)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:614:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 2,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   'openssl pkcs12 -in /tmp/5dcee6b8-6b25-4765-bd17-c0a84d2bcbb5.pfx -nodes -passin pass:brlog18 | tee >(openssl x509 -outform PEM) >(openssl pkey -outform PEM)' }
```

I would like to run that command in this way because I will able to get the private and public key using a single exec command.

Can someone help-me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force node.js to use bin/bash instead of sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460928/force-node-js-to-use-bin-bash-instead-of-sh)

Comment: This happens because you are using Bash-only `>(process substitution)` in a command that's being executed by `sh`. `sh` does not support process substitution. If you want to reproduce it in your local terminal, just run `sh` first and then paste the command at that new prompt.

Comment: Hello dude!
Well, setting {shell: "/bin/bash"} inside of exec, I was able to solve my problem.
At the link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460928/force-node-js-to-use-bin-bash-instead-of-sh) there is a topic describing the following:

"Provided you're on a recent version of Node, you can add the following as option for exec:
{shell: "/bin/bash"}"
Thanks.